# Is probability function for mutually exclusive events a linear operator?

Tags: probability-theory, operator-theory

If the definitive classification criteria for a linear operator are given by:

1. $L(f+g) = L(f) + L(g)$             [for any/every pair of functions, $f$ and $g$]
2. $L(tf) = tL(f)$                   [for any scalar, $t$]

What does this imply for the probability of any two mutually exclusive events?

One knows that for two mutually exclusive events, the probability of one is related to the other by the positive difference of unity and

- $P(A) + P(B) = 1 \rightarrow     P(A) = 1 - P(B)$  [for two mutually exclusive events, $A$ and $B$]
- $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$

Can the probability function over the union of two mutually exclusive events be considered a linear operator then? Or does this just cross completely incompatible areas of maths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me add another answer that has direct bearing on what you asked.
I like the fact that you are trying to bridge two areas of mathematics so please don't take my first answer as being critical. That said, what you have tumbled upon are called *subadditivity* if you interpret $\cup$ as $+$ (The analogy is not perfect but gets the point across). Subadditivity says

$$
f(x+y) \le f(x) + f(y)
$$

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity for more information.

Answer (score 2):

A linear operator is defined over a vector space. I do not know of any general notion of "scalar multiplication" in the case of the "probability operator". That is, there is no analogue of the 2nd condition in the definition of a linear operator in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write this as a comment but I feel that it is important enough that it should be in the answer. This does not directly answer your question. For that look at voldemort's answer.

There is a common misunderstanding that mutually exclusive means that the events are complementary. Thus if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive you cannot conclude that $P(B)=1-P(A)$. All it means that $A$ and $B$ both cannot occur. All you can conclude are
$$
P(A \cap B) = 0\\
P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)
$$
In plain English,

- *Probability of A **and** B is zero*,
- *Probability of A **or** B is probability of A **plus** probability of B*

You cannot conclude anything else

Comment: Thank you for including your input. What you say makes complete sense, but I feel the interpretation of them as being complementary which you discredit is not only valid, but even necessary. How else can one attach any quantitative measure to metrics like the expected value. I did not mean to imply that probability that both occur is finite or, for that matter, even exists -- it certainly does not. But for situations of either-or outcomes of two [mutually exclusive] events, certainly the probability that one occurs must equal the difference of unity and the probability that the occur does not?

Comment: Not really. Consider the case of random integers. Let event $A$ be that the number is divisible by $5$. Let $B$ be the event that the last digit of the number is $6$. The two events are clearly mutually exclusive. But they are not complimentary since they do not encompass**all** possible outcomes.